# Errno13 - Permission denied in documents folder?

Tags: python, io, copy, errno, shutil

Okay, I worked for an hour on an code which allows the user to create an project, but now I am stunning. I try to copy a file using `shutil` and `copyfile`. Here is my code:

```
class Adder():
    @staticmethod
    def AddResource(resourcepath,resourcename,rootpath,projectname):
        resfi = rootpath + projectname + "/" + projectname + ".sceneproj/Resources"
        resfo = rootpath + projectname + "/" + projectname + ".sceneproj/project.scresources"
        shutil.copyfile(resourcepath + resourcename, resfo) # copy resource into resource folder
        with open(resfi, 'a') as resfile:
            resfile.write("project.scresources/" + resourcename)
            resfile.close()
```

And for starting:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    adder = Adder()
    adder.AddResource('/users/jan/downloads/', 'polygon_grey_background.jpg', '/users/jan/documents/', 'MyCoolScene')
```

But now I get the following problem:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "project.py", line 28, in
>   
>       adder.AddResource('/users/jan/downloads/', 'polygon_grey_background.jpg', '/ users/jan/documents/',
>   'MyCoolScene')   File "project.py", line 21, in AddResource
>       shutil.copyfile(resourcepath + resourcename, resfo) # copy resource into res ource folder   File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py",
>   line 83, in copyfile
>       with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst: IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/users/jan/documents/MyCoolScene/MyCoolS
>   cene.sceneproj/project.scresources'

It means that I don't have the permission to copy the file? But its my `Documents` folder? How can I fix this?

~Jan

Answer (score 4):

Fixed this by using `copy` instead of `copyfile`.

Comment: not in my case though